# How to "source" a specific variable

Tags: linux, bash

Let's say I have two bash scripts:

**Provider.sh**, which performs some process and needs to "expose" `MAP`, but not `A` or `B`:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A MAP
A=hello
B=world
MAP[hello]=world
```

**Consumer.sh**, which executes `Provider.sh` and needs to use `MAP`.

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./Provider.sh
echo ${MAP[hello]}  # >>> world
```

In order to declutter the environment as much as possible, I want as little as possible in `Provider.sh` to be visible to `Consumer.sh`. How can make it so that only MAP is "sourced".

Comment: If you just need a single value, you can of course just `echo "world"` in `Provider.sh` and use `MAP="$(./Provider.sh)"` in `Consumer.sh`. It might not solve your problem, but well that of someone else who sees this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to scope variables using functions. Example:

```
## Provider.sh
# Global vars
declare -A map

# Wrap the rest of Provider.sh in a function

provider() {

    # Local vars only available in this function
    declare a=hello b=world c d


    # Global vars are available
    map[hello]=world

}

provider "$@"    # Execute function, pass on any positional parameters

# Remove function
unset -f provider
```

---

```
$ cat Consumer.sh
. ./Provider.sh
echo "${map[hello]}"
echo "$a"
```

```
$ bash -x Consumer.sh
+ . ./Provider.sh
++ declare -A map
++ provider
++ declare a=hello b=world c d
++ map[hello]=world
++ unset -f provider
+ echo world
world
+ echo ''
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function and make the variables local or global:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo() {
  declare -gA MAP # make global
  local A=hello # make local
  local B=world # make local
  MAP[hello]=world
}

foo
```

Then:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./Provider.sh
[[ -z "$A" ]] && echo "Variable A not defined"
[[ -z "$B" ]] && echo "Variable B not defined"
echo ${MAP[hello]}
```

Output:

```
Variable A not defined
Variable B not defined
world
```

Comment: +1 for introducing function and scoping concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a way to source just part of a shell script.  You can either source the entire thing or nothing at all.

However, you could use `grep` to extract only the lines you want from the file and write them into a new file, which you could then source.  That, of course, won't work if you have some complicated function that feeds into your code.

In any event, it's better to split this code out into multiple scripts and source only the things you need.  If you want to have just one script, you could also place your code into multiple functions, source it from multiple locations, and call just the function you need.

Comment: `source <( grep thing filename )`

Answer (score 0):

When you say `source` and have two files, I am thinking that you are wanting to have the two commands available at the command line and want provider to set the variable for the consumer to use later. (Ah, I see that consumer sources producer, so they will share the same namespace, and consumer will not pollute it's calling namespace.

I use functions for some of bash_aliases, and source the file that includes the function definitions from `.bashrc`. This way they set and use variables in the current shell, not a subshell where they will disappear after it runs.

When I have a bash file that must be sourced to work, I put a reminder in it with the `shebang`:

```
#!/bin/echo "You have to source this file (${BASH_SOURCE}), not run it"
# -*-mode:sh;sh-shell:bash;fill-column:84-*-
```

Note that `/bin/echo` is used rather than /bin/bash so that when it is run, it only echos the first line.

Also `${BASH_SOURCE}` will give the user a hint to the location of the file.

The second line `# -*-mode:sh;sh-shell:bash;fill-column:84-*-` is for Emacs to figure out how to highlight and indent the file when I edit it.

The two functions provided by guest are great, but if put in separate files will not be active if you just run the files.

SO, I have taken guest's code here, but with some changes to do what I think that you might want.  Also with the proviso that they are put in a file to be sourced.

```
#!/bin/echo "You have to source this file (${BASH_SOURCE}), not run it"
# -*-mode:sh;sh-shell:bash;fill-column:84-*-
# define producer and consumer functions

declare -A MAP  # you might want to use a different name 
                # because this is going to be in your global namespace

function provider() {
    local A=hello
    local B=world
    MAP[hello]=world   
}

## However maybe what you are wanting is a setter function instead?
function providerSetter() {
    MAP[${1}] = ${2}
}

function consumer()
    echo ${MAP[hello]}
}

## Again, you might want a getter function
function consumerGetter()
    echo ${MAP[${1}]}
}

## you can put defaults into the second functions, i.e.,
function providerSetter2() {
    MAP[${1:-hello}] = ${2:-world}
}
function consumerGetter2()
    echo ${MAP[${1:-hello}]}
}
```

Welcome to the forums!